# How to use flask combine vue

Tags: python, vue.js, flask

I try this website --> https://codeburst.io/full-stack-single-page-application-with-vue-js-and-flask-b1e036315532
but **virtualenv** is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file. *in Window10*
What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither *Flask* or *virtualenv* are related to VueJS. Just saying this out loud for clarification. Now that's out of the way

### This is the command you're looking for

```sh
pip install virtualenv
```

Consider checking the date of the tutorials you're following also. This is old. Try newer
[image: flask-vue]

Comment: Can you suggest me.About newer pls. Thanks a lot

Comment: The number one resource is the vuejs website. Over there you can learn everything you need to with code samples. https://vuejs.org Try the 'get started'